# Eclipse cannot resolve import of cordova 2.1.0 files

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to use the Android [InAppBilling](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling) plugin in my Cordova 2.1.0 app.

**source:** https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

I'm following all the instruction steps, but Eclipse show me errors:

```
for CordovaAbstractBillingObserver.java:
The import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;  cannot be resolved

for InAppBillingPlugin.java
The import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;  cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;  cannot be resolved
```

How can I resolve these errors?

It realy very strange errors, because I have added cordova jar file as library, and errors not fixed. Please anybody know what is the problem ?

Comment: It seems like I cannot import org.cordova in my plugin's code, please somebody help me to understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you cordova.jar library has been correctly included in your buildpath (Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the cordova.jar file).

I would also recommend to **upgrade at least to Cordova 2.3** (the plugin as been made for Cordova 2.3).

Comment: All this was done, and errors still not fixed. I even tried to install cordova 2.3 and same errors.

Comment: The org.apache.cordova package is included in Cordova.jar. If you need me to login into your machine to do the work, I can do it but it will not be free.

Comment: ok, then tell me an estimate for that fix, it is realy something minor with which I'm not experienced with. Thanks

Comment: give me a link to post this issue again, so we can start discuss closely on that issue which need an individual attention to fix it.

Comment: Please send me an email using this form: http://www.smartmobilesoftware.com/contact.html . Thank you.